# static vs. instance versions of Regex.Match in C#

Tags: c#, regex, performance

I've noticed some code that uses the static method:

```
Regex.IsMatch([someRegexStr], [someInputStr])
```

Is it worth replacing it with the instance method? Like:

```
private readonly Regex myRegex = new Regex([someRegexStr]);

...

myRegex.IsMatch([someInputStr]);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the regular expression optimization recommendations in the following link: 
[Regular Expression Optimization](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=692) by [Jim Mischel](http://www.informit.com/authors/bio.aspx?a=18e9dac3-3dc6-4110-b55c-550e5f9bbfee)

*For better performance on commonly used regular expressions, construct a Regex object and call its instance methods.*

The [article](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=692) contains interesting topics such as caching regular expressions and compiling regular expressions along with optimization recommendations.

Comment: This says pretty much the opposite. It toally depends on what style of search you are doing.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2010/06/25/optimizing-regular-expression-performance-part-i-working-with-the-regex-class-and-regex-objects.aspx

Answer (score 5):

The last 15 regular expression internal representations created from the static call are cached.

I talk about this and the internal workings in "[How .NET Regular Expressions Really Work](http://www.moserware.com/2009/03/how-net-regular-expressions-really-work.html)."

Answer (score 3):

There is some initial processing that happens when you call the static `Regex.IsMatch()` method - essentially to validate your regular expression and convert it into a finite state machine representation.

If you plan on running the same regex match multiple times, you are probably better off instantiating a Regex instance, and calling the instance IsMatch() method. You can have the epxression compiled into CLR bytecode using the `RegexOptions.Compiled` flag, which improves performance even more.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, especially if you can make it a compiled expression. It's slower to construct the `Regex` object this way, but much faster to use for a net win.

Edit: Potentially (probably++) much faster. There's no requirement that the CLI have a good optimization, but I'm going to guess that Microsoft's certainly is. :D

```
private readonly Regex myRegex = new Regex([someRegexStr], RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Comment: This can be much faster, but should only be used if this same regex is used more than once.