# Separating lines to textbox (vb 2008)

Tags: vb.net

[image]

I want to set like this

- In first textbox I want 1st line
- in second textbox I want 2nd line

and so one...

```
        prezime.Text = "Vukmirovic" 'I want this to show in textbox
        ime.Text = ""
        jmbg.Text = ""
        pol.Text = ""
        daniz.Text = ""
        meseciz.Text = ""
        godinaiz.Text = ""
        danr.Text = ""
        mesecr.Text = ""
        godinar.Text = ""
        danvd.Text = ""
        mesecvd.Text = ""
        godinavd.Text = ""
        regbr.Text = ""
        brojtel.Text = ""
        adresa.Text = ""
        grad.Text = ""
        opstina.Text = "" <code>
```

OK , i writed down the code so that Prezime: is replaced with nothing. I imported

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

Now i just have to set that first line is set for prezime.text , second for ime.text and so one , help :)

```
RichTextBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(RichTextBox1.Text, "Prezime: ", "")
```

Comment: Is it VB.NET or VBA (Excel, Access, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using .NET

```
     '...
     Dim i As Integer = 0
     Dim myFile As String = "C:\Temp\infile.txt"
     'it would be good to add a try/catch here in case you get an io error
     Dim lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(myFile)
     prezime.Text = splitter(lines(i))
     ime.Text = splitter(lines(++i))
     'do the same for other text boxes 
     'you need to code the lines in the same order as input file values
     lastRow.Text = splitter(lines(++i))
     '...

 Private Shared Function splitter(ByVal parmLine As String) As String
     'split the passed string into 2 srings using the : as a separator 
     Dim words() As String = parmLine.Split(":")
     'test to see you have 2 words returned. If not, error
     If (words.Length < 2) Then
         Return "Error reading from file - Expected 2 tokens spearated by : but found 1"
     End If
     'you don't care about the first word it is the field name. Return the 2nd
     Return words(1).Trim
 End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a textbox to hold your file's content.

```
Public Function whichtxt(ByVal line As Integer) As TextBox
    If line = 0 Then
        Return TextBox2
    ElseIf line = 1 Then
        Return TextBox3
'And so on... 
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox1.Lines.Length - 1
        Dim s As String = TextBox1.Lines(i)
        whichtxt(i).Text = s
    Next
```

Comment: What it doesn't work? On mine it does... [here](http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/7733/htqc.png) 

wasn't this you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

First we'll write a function to parse the actual part of the input we want from each line:

```
Private Function GetDataFromLine(line As String) As String
    'Find everything before and including ': ' and remove it
    Return Regex.Replace(line, ".*: ", String.Empty)
End Function
```

*Note: Calling the static regex methods versus creating a regex instance has some performance loss, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1155879/945456) for more details.*

Then we'll read all the lines from the file and put them in the appropriate fields:

```
Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("myfile.txt")
prezime.Text = GetDataFromLine(lines(0))
ime.Text = GetDataFromLine(lines(1))
jmbg.Text = GetDataFromLine(lines(2))
'...
```

---

Another possible way to solve this, would be to map your input data into a dictionary that would look like this:

```
"Prezime" => "Vukmirovic"
"Ime" => "Nemanja"
...
```

and then do something like:

```
prezime.Text = inputDictionary("Prezime")
```

You'd have to write a function that'd map the input file to a dictionary.

Comment: OK , i writed down the code so that Prezime: is replaced with nothing.
I imported System.Text.RegularExpressions
Now i just have to set that first line is set for prezime.text , second for ime.text and so one , help :)


    RichTextBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(RichTextBox1.Text, "Prezime: ", "")

Comment: So you loaded the file into the `RichTextBox` from the file and you're reading your input from the `RichTextBox`? If you, simply replace `File.ReadAllLines(...)` with `RichTextBox1.Lines` (assuming you're using WinForms and not WPF).

Comment: Error Name 's' is not declared.




    Private Function GetDataFromLine(line As String) As String
        'Find everything before and including ': ' and remove it
        Return Regex.Replace(s, ".*: ", String.Empty)
    End Function

Comment: Fixed the mistake: `s` should be `line`. I forgot to change it when copying my test code into the post.