# Regex to match one word and not a list of others

Tags: c#, regex, c#-3.0

I'm writing a c# application.

I'm trying to write a regex which would match a string against a pattern as such:

The aim is testing whether the string matches the pattern: any char any number of time, then a period, then bla and not blo, bli nor blu, then a period, then a list of extensions. It also needs to be case insensitive.

Here is what I have so far

```
var pattern = string.Format(@".*\.(?i){0}\.(?:ext|ext1|ext2|ext3)", "bla");
```

It works fine for finding strings with bla. Now, I'd like to be able to filter out a list of three chars strings in the exact same position.

I have a list of FileInfo items

- example of fileName any char will do.**bla**.ext
- example of fileName any char will do.**bla**.ext1
- example of fileName any char will do.**bla**.ext2
- example of fileName any char will do.**blu**.ext
- example of fileName any char will do.**blo**.ext1
- example of fileName any char will do.**bli**.ext2

and I'd like to retrieve those who match the pattern described above like so:

- example of fileName any char will do.**bla**.ext
- example of fileName any char will do.**bla**.ext1
- example of fileName any char will do.**bla**.ext2

These are ok.

- example of fileName any char will do.**blu**.ext
- example of fileName any char will do.**blo**.ext1
- example of fileName any char will do.**bli**.ext2

These ain't.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: which language is it?

Comment: What is the `{0}` for? Is it a parameter placeholder? If so, could you provide sample input and output

Comment: I have updated my answer. But I really recommend you to edit your question so it can be used by other people having similar Regex questions (Like searching for files with certain extensions).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why are you keep making it complex by using things like `string.Format()` or `(?i)` or `(?:ext|ext1|ext2|ext3)`. Try:

```
var list = Directory.GetFiles(path).Where(file => Regex.IsMatch(file, @"^.+\.bla\.ext[1-3]*$", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)).ToList();
```

And of course I recommend using an instance of a Regex instead of using the static IsMatch method for better [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155694/static-vs-instance-versions-of-regex-match-in-c-sharp), but I'm going to let you do that by yourself.

Comment: I edited my question, hopefuly it gives a better understanding of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Allright, I did it the other way around, by retrieving all the files but the ones who match the following pattern

```
var pattern = string.Format(@".*\.(?i)(?:{0})\.(?:ext|ext1|ext2|ext3)", new List<string>() { "bli", "blo", "blu"});

listTmp.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(myPath))
                          .Where(f => !new Regex(pattern).IsMatch(f)).ToList());
```